# Is there any advantage of using integer instead of long, in vb.net if we want to code for 64 bit computers only?

Tags: vb.net

Is there advantage?

32 bit computers aren't around anymore right?

Is there any reason why we should use 32 bit integer?

Do we save spaces?

Do we save memories?

One use I can think of is to communicate with 32 bit API or for something very special. But normally, we don't have any use right?

Comment: No, accessing memory is by far the slowest thing a processor needs to do.  Locality of reference is crucial to keep the caches efficient.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure "no" is the the word you want there.  I think the answer is that there is no advantage to using `Long` instead of `Integer` unless you have large enough numbers to need the added width, or you're using a `Long` to represent a pointer.  In fact, `Integer` should be preferred for the efficiency reasons mentioned (maximizing cache usage and memory bandwidth efficiency).

Comment: I think I need to turn this into an answer. Why is integer faster?